# Using an SQL result in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I feel like I am missing something stupidly obvious here, I am trying to get the results of an SQL query and then using them in a loop. I feel like I am missing something stupidly obvious, I have tried it with and without the commented out line.

```
<?php
$sentToID = $_SESSION['userID'];

$query = "SELECT *
          FROM messages
          WHERE sentToID = '$sentToID'";

$results = mysql_query($query);
//$userData = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC);

foreach ($results as $result){
    $messageID = $result['messageID'];
    $sentFromID = $result['sentFromID'];
    $subject = $result['subject'];
    $body = $result['body'];
    $dateTime = $result['dateTime'];

    $query = "SELECT usertype 
              FROM user
              WHERE userID = '$sentFromID'";
    $messageResult = mysql_query($query);
    $messageData = mysql_fetch_array($messageResult, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    $usertype = $messageData['usertype'];

    $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM $usertype
              WHERE userID = '$sentFromID'";

    $messageResult = mysql_query($query);
    $messageData = mysql_fetch_array($messageResult, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    if ($usertype == "jobseeker"){
        $forname = $messageData['forename'];
        $surname = $messageData['surname'];
        echo "<div><p>" . $forename . " " . $surname . "</p>
              <p>Subject: " . $subject ."</p>
              <p>Body: " . $body . "</p></div>";
    }
    if ($usertype == "employer"){
        $forname = $messageData['forename'];
        $surname = $messageData['surname'];
        $companyName = $messageData['companyName'];

        echo "<div><p>" . $forename . " " . $surname . " - " . $companyName . "</p>
              <p>Subject: " . $subject ."</p>
              <p>Body: " . $body . "</p></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: When uncommented, shouldn't the foreach read `foreach($userData as $result)`?

Comment: We can't help you if you won't tell us what the problem is. Anyway, to work with the array you need to use the array, not the query! Meaning, you have `$result` in your `foreach` instead of `$userData`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must first fetch your results into an array. Looks like you started to do this but commented it out.

```
$results = mysql_query($query);
//$userData = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$resultset = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
  $resultset[] = $row;
}

// $resultset now holds all rows from the first query.
foreach ($resultset as $result){
 //... etc...
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of your `foreach()`, you should do something like this (see the [mysql_query() manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for more):

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

another option

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result)
for ($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++) {
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
$messageID = $row['messageID'];
}
```

You can do anything from here.

Remember,
1- query into object like $result
2- fetch row at a time from the object into an array which reflects an entire row in the table given your query definition with associative keys or numeric
3- do something with the array

You will loop through the object row by row and put in $row as an array.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to comment, and the above answers are correct, but the [php mysql_query() manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) says that

> this extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
> 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

So now a correct way would be:

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the **$results = mysql_query($query);** is a resource of type object. For example:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { 
  ["current_field"] => int(0) 
  ["field_count"] => int(3) 
  ["lengths"] => NULL 
  ["num_rows"] => int(2) 
  ["type"] => int(0) 
}
```

Since, we are only interested with the table data. We have the pass the resource to `mysql_fetch_array()`, and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data according to [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

We cannot directly use it.

However, If you are having problem understanding the inner working of while loop i will give you an example.

```
<?php

    $s = 0;

    class deepe {
        function dis(){
            $a = array(2,3,4,5,6);
            $b = $GLOBALS['s'];
            if ( $b < count($a) )
                return $a[$b];
        }
    }

    $chk = new deepe();

    while($fac = $chk->dis())
    {
        echo $fac."<br />";
        $GLOBALS['s']++;
    }

?>
```