# how to acess my database elements using the for loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I'm learning `PHP` and I'm well versed with `Java` and `C`. I was given a practice assignment to create a shopping project. I need to pull out the products from my database. I'm using the product id to do this. I thought of using for loop but I can't access the `prod_id` from the database as a condition to check! Can anybody help me?! I have done all the form handling but I need to output the products. This is the `for`-loop I am using. Please let me know if I have to add any more info. Thanks in advance :)

```
for($i=1; $i + 1 < prod_id; $i++)
{
   $query = "SELECT * FROM products where prod_id=$i";
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538511/using-an-sql-result-in-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, you should use [database access drivers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php) to connect to your database.
2. Your query should not be passed to cycle. It is very rare situation, when such approach is needed. Better to use `WHERE` condition clause properly.
3. To get all rows from `products` table you may just ommit `WHERE` clause. Consider reading of [**manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) at http://dev.mysql.com/doc.

> The statement selects all rows if there is no WHERE clause.

Following example is for [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/mysqli) driver.

```
// connection to MySQL:
// replace host, login, password, database with real values.
$dbms = mysqli_connect('host', 'login', 'password', 'database');

// if not connected then exit:
if($dbms->connect_errno)exit($dbms->connect_error);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

// executing query:
$result = $dbms->query($sql);

// if query failed then exit:
if($dbms->errno)exit($dbms->error);

// for each result row as $product:
while($product = $row->fetch_assoc()){
    // output:
    var_dump($product); // replace it with requied template
}

// free result memory:
$result->free();

// close dbms connection:
$dbms->close();
```

Comment: @NullPoiиteя unfortunately, I'm not working with PDO and using MySQLi. I do not want to write code, that I never used. You may supply example aswell. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use PDO. This method will secure all your SQLand will keep all your connections closed and intact.

Here is an example

**EXAMPLE.**
This is your dbc class (dbc.php)

```
<?php

class dbc {

    public $dbserver = 'server';
    public $dbusername = 'user';
    public $dbpassword = 'pass';
    public $dbname = 'db';

    function openDb() {    
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbserver . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $this->dbusername . '', '' . $this->dbpassword . '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("error, please try again");
        }        
        return $db;
    }

    function getproduct($id) {
        //prepared query to prevent SQL injections
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products where prod_id=?";
        $stmt = $this->openDb()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $rows;
    }    
?>
```

your PHP page:

```
<?php 
require "dbc.php";
for($i=1; $i+1<prod_id; $i++) 
{

$getList = $db->getproduct($i);
//for each loop will be useful Only if there are more than one records (FYI)
foreach ($getList as $key=> $row) {
         echo $row['columnName'] .' key: '. $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for pdo ....always do `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/12202218#12202218

Comment: what  is a pdo? this is the first im cming across this term?

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1;$i+1<prod_id;$i++) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products where prod_id=$i";
    $result = mysqli_query($query, $con);
```

$con is the Database connection details
you can use wile loop to loop thru each rows

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might work as per your need..

```
for($i=1; $i+1<prod_id; $i++) {
   $query  = "SELECT * FROM products where prod_id = $i";
   $result = mysql_query($query);

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
         print_r($row);  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want all records from your table, if this is the requirement you can easily do it

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products"); // where condition is optional   

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   print_r($row);
   echo '<br>';
}
```

This will print an associative array for each row, you can access each field like

```
echo $row['prod_id'];
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).